# Authentication with Identity, OpenID & JWT

Tags: jwt, blazor, asp.net-identity, openid, .net-8.0

Yeah, I know I'm asking for a lot. So basically what I want is this:
I want to use the built-in (local) authentication routines using Microsoft Identity. I also want to authenticate against an OpenID-Server. And to top it off, handing over a JWT access token should work as well.

Now, I got two out of the three (Identity and JWT) working whereas OpenID authenticates but then has problems with getting user info.

Let me show you: With this code I can auth both Identity and OpenID perfectly:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    }).AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("OIDC", opt);
        opt.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.Configuration["OIDC:RedirectUri"];
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        };
    }).AddIdentityCookies();
```

When you authenticate using OpenID, upon your first login you're asked to enter some local info which then gets associated with your OpenID info in the database. This has the advantage that you can use local and external credentials to point to the same account.

Now, then I added JWT authentication. [According to Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) the only solution I could find which allows for different `Scheme`s is this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        //options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        //options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = "Identity_or_JWT";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Identity_or_JWT";

    }).AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("OIDC", opt);
        opt.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.Configuration["OIDC:RedirectUri"];
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        };
    }).AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "https://foo",
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://foo",
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobarbaz"))
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Append("Token-Expired", "true");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                               (path.StartsWithSegments("/chatHub")))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })
    .AddPolicyScheme("Identity_or_JWT", "Identity_or_JWT", options =>
    {
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
        {
            string? authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization)) { 
                if (endpoint?.DisplayName?.Contains("ExternalLogin") == true)
                {
                    return IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                } else
                {
                    return IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                }
            }           

            return "Bearer";
        };
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();
```

Now, this works for Identity and also for JWT. It fails on the OpenID part - namely that while it does authenticate, associating the OpenID user with the local user fails miserably.
You can see that I already tried something which differentiates between "Logins" and "Normal Auth" but that didn't make much of a difference.
Anyone have an idea where to go from here? I mean, I'm *almost* there.

edit: So, to further clarify where the problem lies: Normally, when a user logs in via OpenID, there should be a lookup whether that OpenID-user is already associated with a local user. It then either retrieves the local user or redirect to a form where you have to *once* create a local user. This last part is not happening, leaving you in a limbo where you're authenticated but actual user-info (like names and such) are not available.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what is happening? Why do you want to associate users? Can't they sign in using the OpenID provider? Is doing it just with Identity a requirement? Take a look [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core).

Comment: Here's the thing: Local users should exist to provide a) a fallback admin account and b) to future-proof because it'll start out locally but at some point will switch over to OpenID.
Also that way I can support multiple auth sources for the same user - currently it's in flux and some orgs (which will be connected to this app) might have their own OpenID-Server.